# Perfect toroidal graphs

Tags: graph-theory

A toroidal graph is perfect if every vertex has same degree $d$ and every
face has the same number of edges $k$. I am asked to come up with possible values of $d$ and $k$ and to construct an innite series of examples of perfect toroidal graphs. But I am a little lost. I tried starting from the toroidal property ( Euler characteristic $= 0$) but it didn't lead me anywhere. The only relationship I came up with is $dV= 2E$ but I don't know how to approach$k$. Any hints/suggestions?

Comment: You can use "every face has $k$ edges" to come up with an equation relating the number of faces to the number of edges.

Comment: If you have found that one of the answers does the trick for you, you can "accept" it by clicking in the check mark next to it. If your question hasn't been resolved to your satisfaction, please let us know what more you need.

Comment: Are you still here, bluemuse?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$V-E+F=0$ from the Euler characteristic. As you say, $dV = 2E$ because both count half-edges. But $kF$ also counts half-edges. So $2E/d - E + 2E/k = 0$ or $2k + 2d = dk$. Thus $d=\frac{2k}{k-2}$ and vice versa. Can you take it from here?

Comment: Thank you so much! How would you advise me to approach the infinite series?

Comment: do you have an example of an infinite series for general toroidal graphs? something to help me picture it and apply the special case (perfect) to it?

Comment: I was familiar with an example even before I knew the term "graph theory". Many classic computer games (most famously Asteroids, Pacman, and some versions of Snake) were played on a topological torus... That gives you an answer for the middle value of $d$. It can be distorted to produce answers for the other values of $d$.

Answer (score 0):

You know how to "make" a torus by taking a square and identifying opposite edges in pairs? Well, before you do the identification, pick a positive integer $n$, and draw in an $n\times n$ grid on the square. Now when you do the identification, that grid becomes a graph on the torus, where every vertex has degree 4, and every face has 4 edges. So, there's an infinite family.